# What is the best solution for Airflow deploying on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, airflow, amazon-ecs, amazon-eks

I've been thinking with my team which solution is the best for deploying Apache Airflow on AWS in terms of cost and performance. We did some research and found out some solutions, among them using Kubernetes (EKS), a machine on EC2 and using ECS (Fargate). But, on Google there isn't so much detailed contents about it. Also, we did some estimates based on our calculations, however, we're not so sure about that. We are looking for a discussion about the trade off of each solution.

So, my question is: is there someone who is going through this or someone who has been through this? And, which is, if exists, the best solution?

Answer (score 2):

In late 2020, AWS [announced](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-amazon-managed-workflows-for-apache-airflow-mwaa/) Amazon Managed Workflows for Apache Airflow (MWAA). It is a fully managed service that makes it easy to run open-source versions of Apache Airflow (including v2) on AWS.

I'd suggest having a read through [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/what-is-mwaa.html) to find out more and determine if it meets your requirements.

From my personal experience: I had previously managed an Airflow stack using EC2 and ECS worker pools. Moving over to MWAA has definitely been a better solution & provided a much better user experience.